# Solspace Rating: adding parameter inside the <form>

Tags: forms, parameters, solspace-rating

I'm using Rating from Solspace, and at the same time I use **Zurb Foundation Abide validation library**.

My goal is the **data-abide** **Zurb Foundation** parameter appears  inside the form element created by the Rating module:

```
<form data-abide>
```

How it's possible that this parameter **data-abide** appears inside the **form element** when the HTML form is created by the Rating module ?

Comment: Have you tried using the form:attribute parameter?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your help, Blatant has developped your tip. I tried with a wrong syntax and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://solspace.com/docs/rating/form/#form:attribute) (and as Jim says) Try using the `form:attribute parameter. Something like this :

```
form:data-abide=""
```

Might work, might strip the empty tag, however even if not this should get it on the form, it's just if Abide will recognise the data attribute with the 'false' value set.

```
form:data-abide="data-abide"
```

Otherwise, without rereating the form tags yourself (and losing all the tags inside) you could perhaps target the form (or all forms with a js snippet and reflow the abide stuff, summin like :

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-abide','');
    $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
});
```

Abide Docs : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html#adding-new-abide-content-after-page-load

Comment: Blatant, thanks for your help!! really form:data-abide="" is working fine. The js snippet is a nice alternative.